# Is it correct to say " Is mr.John in travel"?

Tags: phrases

Is this correct?

> Is mr.John in Travel?

Comment: If you're currently learning English, you may be interested in our sister site, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not correct. You could say:

1. Is Mr. John traveling?
2. Is Mr. John in transit?

Your sentence is treating "travel" as a noun while you're trying to convey an action (i.e., traveling).

Check out [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/verb-tenses-adding-ed-and-ing) for a nice primer on the infinitive and conjugations.

Answer (score 1):

Using "Travel" with a capital T makes it a proper noun, which could be the name of a department dealing with travel arrangements. "Is Mr John in Travel? Or is he in Accounts? Or Marketing?"

Such a question would be correct.

If you intend the question to ask whether Mr John is currently travelling from one place to another, it's not correct because you need a present continuous verb, *is travelling.*

> Is Mr John travelling?

Idiomatically, this tends to refer to the future (the "present" tense in English is colloquially used for future intention), so to make it clear that you are asking about whether he is in transit at the moment you ask, use a word like *currently:* "Is Mr John currently travelling?"

Note that *Mr,* being a title, always gets a capital letter. The dot after it is generally optional, but if you use it then it's always followed by a space.